# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to filter an aggregation based on the results of sub-aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter aggregations based on results of two different sub-aggregations. The use case here is to get a list of accounts that have non-zero values when searching through an index of transactions. Where the transactions `_source` looks similar to the following

```
"_source": {
  "debit": 50,
  "account_id": "account-id-1"
}

"_source": {
  "credit": 50,
  "account_id": "account-id-1"
}

"_source": {
  "debit": 25,
  "account_id": "account-id-2"
}

"_source": {
  "credit": 50,
  "account_id": "account-id-2"
}
```

at the moment I'm using an aggregation query like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms_account_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "account_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_debit": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "debit"
          }
        },
        "sum_credit": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "credit"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives results like this

```
"aggregations": {
    "terms_account_id": {      
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "account-id-1",
          "sum_credit": { "value": 50 },
          "sum_debit": { "value": 50 }
        },
        {
          "key": "account-id-2"
          "sum_credit": { "value": 50 },
          "sum_debit": { "value": 25 }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

then afterwards I'm looping through the `terms_account_id.buckets` and comparing their `sum_debit` and `sum_credit` amounts to find accounts with non-zero values.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to filter the `terms_account_id` aggregation by some sort of aggregation filter whereby it looks at the `sum_credit` and `sum_debit` sub aggregations and if they are equal it omits them from the results so that the end result is something like this

```
"aggregations": {
    "terms_account_id": {      
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "account-id-2"
          "sum_credit": { "value": 50 },
          "sum_debit": { "value": 25 }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

or even

```
"aggregations": {
    "terms_account_id": {      
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "account-id-2"
          "sum_total": { "value": 25 },
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I've been reading the Elasticsearch documentation and I've seen its possible to filter aggregations based on _source fields, but I couldn't find anything about filtering based on sub aggregations. Since the code I have is currently working that could just be the intended way of leveraging Elasticsearch, but I was wondering if potentially more could be done in the search so as to not return un-needed values.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring it out using a Bucket selector aggregation and a small bit of code in order to compare the other two aggregations.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_terms_account_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "account_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_sum_debit": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "debit"
          }
        },
        "agg_sum_credit": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "credit"
          }
        },
        "agg_bucket_selector_null": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "aggSumCredit": "agg_sum_credit",
              "aggSumDebit": "agg_sum_debit"
            },
            "script": "(params.aggSumCredit == null ? 0 : params.aggSumCredit) != (params.aggSumDebit == null ? 0 : params.aggSumDebit)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

also figured I'd attach the bodybuilder.js syntax since thats what I ended up using:

```
const body = bodybuilder()
    .aggregation('terms', 'account_id', (a) => {
      a.aggregation('sum', 'debit')
      a.aggregation('sum', 'credit')
      return a.aggregation('bucket_selector', null, {
        buckets_path: {
          aggSumCredit: 'agg_sum_credit',
          aggSumDebit: 'agg_sum_debit'
        },
        script: '(params.aggSumCredit == null ? 0 : params.aggSumCredit) != (params.aggSumDebit == null ? 0 : params.aggSumDebit)'
      })
    })
    .size(0)
```